# How do I align my label to the left of my text input box with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to all of this so I have a question and it's probably silly but here we go anyway.

I have this HTML for a form but I need to use CSS to align my labels to the left of the text box and *not* have it sit on top. I don't know what CSS to use in order to do this.

```
<form action="process.php">
    <h1>Registration</h1>
    <ol>
        <li>
            <label for="name">Name:</label>
<input type>"text" id="name" name="name">
        </li>
    </ol>
</form>
```

There are three more "labels" like this in my `ol` but I don't feel like typing them all out.

I need the labels to the left aligned with my text boxes.

I have tried:

```
label{display:inline-block}
```

And:

```
label ol{display:inline-block}
```

I've tried giving floats, the text book (yes this is for a college class) says to do this:

```
.label{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

But *that* doesn't seem to work either. Please tell me how on earth I can do this.

Here is my exact CSS so far:

```
h1{font-family:Oregano;}

form{margin-bottom:1em;}

form ol{list-style-type:none;}

form li{width:100px;
border:1px solid black;
text-align:right;
background-color:black;
color:white;
margin:20px;
height:20px;
white-space:5px;}
```

It looks exactly like it should, I just have an issue with the alignment of the labels. Have I mentioned how much I hate this crap? I'm changing my major! (not really... but still)

Comment: `.label`: All elements with class="label".   `label ol`: All `<ol>` elements that are nested inside at least one `<label>` element.

Comment: label, input,li{
    display:inline-block;
}  make all these to inline-block if you want in one line

Comment: Where are your input elements? It's hard to style it all together without the inputs being shown in your markup.

Comment: This may be dumb of me... but there is no class... there's an id in the text input field but I'm not working on those yet. I'll edit my question to add the input field... hold on...

Comment: There we go... I forgot to add that... sorry.

Comment: Please include enough CSS to reproduce your issue. As it stands, your label and input element *are* inline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this? If so, then no CSS is needed.

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" value="some text" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" value="some text" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" value="some text" />
  </li>
</ol>
```

---

#### So using your updated CSS here is a Solution:

```css
form {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
form ol {
  list-style-type: none;
}
form li {
  margin: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  white-space: 5px;
}
form label {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <ol>
    <li>
      <label for="name">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" value="some text" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="name">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" value="some text" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="name">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" value="some text" />
    </li>
  </ol>
</form>
```

Comment: AHHHH!!!! I love you! That worked! Gah.. Thank you SO much... so was it just a problem with my layout then? You're the bomb... I'm sure I'll be back today at some point though. Thanks again 100x!

Comment: The problem was you were applying some styles to `<li>`instead of `<label>`, So if this answer solves your issues, please make sure you mark it as accepted :)

Comment: Good lord dear I don't know how to navigate this site like that.... How do I mark is as accepted? Does that give you points or something? Yes, Yes... I know... You'd think I'd know all about it.. but alas... nope. Registering to ask a question was my last resort.

Comment: Please take a look at this  [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) or this [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Both the `label` and the `input` must me `inline`/`inline-block`

```
label, input{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

They of course must be next to each other, with the label on the left side in your case.

Btw: it's not a good idea to have `labels` & `inputs` inside `li` elements

Comment: Why isn't it a good idea to have labels & inputs inside li elements?

Answer (score 0):

If you check your example:

```html
<form action="process.php">
<h1>Registration</h1>
<ol>
<li>
<label for="name">Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="name" />
    </li>
    </ol>
</form>
```

you will see that its like you want by default.

So it must be a problem in some CSS rule that gives display block to the input or label tag (or both)

Try this:

label, input {display:inline-block !important}

"!important" at the end is there just in case you need to override some other rule.

Comment: Nope.. that didn't do anything... let me make sure that I've closed everything out and try again...

Comment: Also check if the input have clear:both maybe. Try to debug the css with inspect elements by removing all other rules attached to the input and label and see what cause the issue.

Comment: While it's clear there's some mystery CSS at work in the OP's code, there should be no reason to use !important. It's a hack designed for worst-case scenarios when you have inline styles; you shouldn't introduce it preemptively, rather only if it's absolutely necessary (it almost never is).